# How to iterate over a Connection

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on a piece of multithreaded code, and I was wondering why `Connection`s don't have `__next__` aliased with `recv`. It would make them much nicer to deal with.

Comment: You can post it on [Python ideas](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly do it yourself.

```
class MyConnection:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.connection.recv()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """Expose connection APIs."""
        return getattr(self.connection, attr)

    def __dir__(self):
        """Forward introspection requests. 

        Enable autocompletion with IPython.

        """
        return dir(self.__class__) + dir(self.connection)

r, w = multiprocessin.Pipe()
reader = MyConnection(r)

...

for data in reader:
    print(data)
```

Comment: This makes it so you don't get the rest of the interface. Can you subclass Connection to get a simply extended object?

Comment: Added in the answer.